# iOS NSURLRequest uploadTaskWithRequest timeout in background iOS 13 only

Tags: objective-c, xcode, background-process, nsurlsession, ios13

I am using AFURLSessionManager with backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier to upload video 
to server. I am splitting video in chunks and performing uploadTaskWithRequest fromFile, and each request is dependent on the previous one, which means that I wait for response from server to send next chunk.

My current implementation allows doing this in foreground and background, and this works really great on iOS 12 but there is an issue with iOS 13. When my app goes in background after couple of successful response from server, uploadTaskWithRequest fromFile suddenly starts receiving "request time out". It seems that there is some kind of limiter on number of request initiated from background. Is anyone aware of this? Can someone gives some directions on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it matter what SDK you link against?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to NSURLSession's background session rate limiter, in iOS has a rate limiter to prevent abuse of background session and keep your application working continuously on the background.

You can create and resume your task, but it will not be executed until this delay expired.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/14854#42352) you can find details about the rate limiter and how it works.

> The delay is reset to 0 whenever the user brings your app to the foreground. It also resets if the delay period elapses without the system resuming or relaunching your app.